# A Banach-Orlicz type exercise

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_{n}$ be series of elements in a complex Banach space $X$ such that for every strictly increasing sequence $\{n(1)<n(2)<\cdot\cdot\cdot\}$ of positive integers the subseries $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} x_{n(j)}$ converges weakly to an element of $X$.  I am trying to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\rho(x_{n})|<\infty$ for each bounded linear functional $\rho$ on $X$. It is pretty much immediate that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \rho(x_{n(j)})<\infty$ for every subsequence $\{n(j)\}$ and each bounded $\rho\in X^{*}$. I feel as if I've exhausted my Banach space techniques and now I am wondering whether it isn't simply a fact that this subseries condition is sufficient for absolute convergence, a fact that I have not been able to verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very elementary. Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ be series of real numbers such that for every strictly increasing sequence $\{n(1)<n(2)<\cdot\cdot\cdot\}$ of positive integers the subseries $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{n(j)}$ converges. Then, by just looking at the positive and negative terms of the series we conclude that $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent. By looking at real and imaginary parts, the same result holds for complex series. Hence, the convergence of $\sum \rho(x_{n(j)})$ for every choice of $(n_j)$ implies converegence of $\sum |\rho(x_{n(j)})|$

Comment: How does breaking up $a_{n}$ into its real and imaginary parts help you to apply the result for real numbers?

Comment: Wow I was being an idiot, I see now thanks